# object tracking in raw h.264 compressed video

Tags: computer-vision, video

I am working on a project that requires me to detect and track a human in a live video from a webcam connected to a Beagleboard xm. I have completed this task using Opencv in pixel domain. The results on the board are very accurate but extremely slow. Many people have suggested me to leave pixel domain and do the same task in an h.264/MPEG-4 compressed video as it would extremely reduce the computational overhead. I have read many research papers but failed to discover any software platform or a library that I can use to analyze and process h.264 compressed videos. I will be thankful if someone can suggest me some library for h.264 compressed video analysis and guide me further.
I know about P and I frames but don't know how to extract them and use which programming software or language to process them.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: A simple google search throws up things like [this.](http://mccb.kaist.ac.kr/research/0701.html) What doesn't that do?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have also come across it many times but they have not mentioned the software platform they are using for object tracking

Comment: OK, so google again: [does this help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668494/free-open-h-264-video-decoding-libraries-non-gpl)?  However, I suspect you're asking for an intermediate-level: doing video processing in the compressed domain. Usually people do not release that, because it's generally no useful for others (it's "research" quality code, which is OK for papers but not for general use).

Comment: So how can I view motion vectors.
Is there any library like opencv which I can use...
I have studied the internal structure of h.264 bitstream, know about P,I,B frames theoretically but cant find a way to analyze them.

Comment: Till now I have opened raw h.264 video in Opencv by decompressing it frame by frame but doing so surely boils down to pixels that I have already done and kills the purpose of taking raw h.264 video

Comment: Most things I've read suggest using the [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) library and rolling your own; sorry, not much of a help I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm having just the same issue you had. I'm using beaglebone black and opencv and logitech C920 for color object tracking. When I used 640x480 pixel format the program works but is slow. When I set it up for 1920x1080 to used h264 the program doesn't display the image. Were you able to find a solution? Thanks Rudy

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @PeterK. Hi Peter both links you supplied seem dead. Do you have updated advice on this problem as I'm trying to understand if it's possible to do CV tasks on compressed video instead of raw video. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Crashalot Both links work for me? I'll have more of a dig a little later.

Comment: @PeterK. odd. both links are dead ... are the links somehow geo-protected or are you viewing cached copies possibly? thanks for your help!

Comment: @Crashalot I doubt they're cached or geo-protected. The first one is to SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668494/free-open-h-264-video-decoding-libraries-non-gpl  and the second one is the FFMPEG website: http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: @PeterK. odd the first two links don't appear as you presented them ... thanks for sharing! does it matter from a CV perspective if the source video is raw video or compressed video? obviously working from compressed video reduces bandwidth so that's preferable but wondering if it increases CV processing time or reduces accuracy for CV tasks.